# Finding the hash value of a row in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hashcode

Is there a way to get the hash code of a row in postgresql?

I need to  export some data only if there is some changes in the data after the last export, the last exported data rows can be stored in a table, the when the again I need to export the data I can get the hash values of all the data and export only those rows who has a different hash value than the last export.

Is it possible to achieve using postgresql?

Thank you

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Cast the row to text and use md5 to make a hash:

```
SELECT
    md5(CAST((f.*)AS text))
FROM
    foo f;
```

Comment: OR, shorter `SELECT md5(f::text) FROM f`

Comment: @frank-heikens is there a way to get selective columns and cast them to text? Example- md5(CAST(col_1,col_2,col_3)AS text)

Comment: @johnmich well, md5( (col_1 || col_2 || col_3)::text ) works for me under postgres 12.

Comment: @johnmich @datico Careful! This way different columns can produce the same string, e.g. `'' || '' || 'a' = 'a' || '' || ''`. Better to use `md5(row(col_1,col_2,col_2)::text)`.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach would be to set an [`ON INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) which would insert the current timestamp into a `last_modified` column, and then simply querying based on this column when your import process runs.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is I'm working on a legacy system, where data can come from a import or through add/edit pages and last modified column on all the data is not dependable. That is the reason I'm checking for some kind of hash technique to check for any changes.

Comment: With this approach, the database trigger would be determining and writing the `last_modified` time - not the clients putting data in this table. The clients won't know about this column, and shouldn't - your database would manage it itself.