# Is there a more elegant way to detect changes in a large SQL table without altering it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, checksum

Suppose you have a reasonably large (for local definitions of “large”), but relatively stable table.

Right now, I want to take a checksum of some kind (any kind) of the contents of the entire table.

The naïve approach might be to walk the entire table, taking the checksum (say, MD5) of the concatenation of every column on each row, and then perhaps concatenate them and take its MD5sum.

From the client side, that might be optimized a little by progressively appending columns' values into the MD5 sum routine, progressively mutating the value.

The reason for this, is that at some point in future, we want to re-connect to the database, and ensure that no other users may have mutated the table: that includes INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE.

Is there a nicer way to determine if *any* change/s have occurred to a particular table? Or a more efficient/faster way?

**Update/clarification:**

- We are not able/permitted to make any alterations to the table itself (e.g. adding a “last-updated-at” column or triggers or so forth)

(This is for Postgres, if it helps. I'd *prefer* to avoid poking transaction journals or anything like that, but if there's a way to do so, I'm not against the idea.)

Comment: . . Is the next question after "Did anything change?", "What changed?"?

Comment: Fortunately, no. I'm not the domain expert on this table (in fact, I'm really rehashing this Q for a coworker), but it's really a boolean compare predicate that we're looking-for: `table-sum-stored ≠ checksum(table)`

Comment: @BRPocock If you can't modify the table, I would look at inserting something in the data access layer to capture and alert on table modifications.  If you can't control access to the table, then perhaps the accepted answer to this post will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020033/how-can-i-get-a-hash-of-an-entire-table-in-postgresql, although it still does a full table scan.

Comment: That would be great, if we had a “data access layer.” Of course, if we had such a layer, we wouldn't need this :-) However, the Q you linked looks appropriate, I didn't find that earlier. That looks like there was a winner.

Comment: @BRPocock One more suggestion:  You may want to look at the accepted answer to this post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/determine-when-a-postgresql-database-was-last-changed, using the values in pg_stat_all_tables instead of pg_stat_database.   Also, looks like dba.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question if you're not getting the answer you need.

Comment: That's even better, awesome. Your search-fu has exceeded my humble efforts. Thanks! I should probably term this Q now.

Comment: There's a patch to PostgreSQL in circulation on pgsql-hackers that adds an "md5_agg" function to do just what you want. There's also this, available as an extension: http://llg.cubic.org/pg-mdagg/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update for postgres 10+

Now that logical replication is available in postgres, it's generally the best option for continuous change capture. Use that.

### Adding columns and triggers is really quite safe

While I realise you've said it's a large table in a production DB so you say you can't modify it, I want to explain how you can make a very low impact change.

In PostgreSQL, an `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN` of a nullable column takes only moments and doesn't require a table re-write. It does require an exclusive lock, but the main consequence of that is that it can take a long time before the `ALTER TABLE` can actually proceed, it won't hold anything else up while it waits for a chance to get the lock.

The same is true of creating a trigger on the table.

This means that it's quite safe to add a `modified_at` or `created_at` column and an associated trigger function to maintain them to a live table that's in intensive real-world use. Rows added before the column was created will be null, which makes perfect sense since you don't know when they were added/modified. Your trigger will set the `modified_at` field whenever a row changes, so they'll get progressively filled in.

For your purposes it's probably more useful to have a trigger-maintained side-table that tracks the timestamp  of the last change (insert/update/delete) anywhere in the table. That'll save you from storing a whole bunch of timestamps on disk and will let you discover when deletes have happened. A single-row side-table with a row you update on each change using a `FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger will be quite low-cost. It's not a good idea for most tables because of contention - it essentially serializes all transactions that attempt to write to the table on the row update lock. In your case that might well be fine, since the table is large and rarely updated.

A third alternative is to have the side table accumulate a running log of the timestamps of insert/update/delete statements or even the individual rows. This allows your client read the change-log table instead of the main table and make small changes to its cached data rather than invalidating and re-reading the whole cache. The downside is that you have to have a way to periodically purge old and unwanted change log records.

So... there's really no *operational* reason why you can't change the table. There may well be business policy reasons that prevent you from doing so even though you know it's quite safe, though.

### ... but if you really, really, really can't:

Another option is to use the existing "md5agg" extension: http://llg.cubic.org/pg-mdagg/ . Or to apply [the patch currently circulating pgsql-hackers to add an "md5_agg" to the next release](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAEZATCUq--+zYAQxYfyO+3oPjCY6DWS5scET8PPHA7mhn7WDxg@mail.gmail.com) to your PostgreSQL install if you built from source.

### Logical replication

The [bi-directional replication for PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide) project has produced functionality that allows you to listen for and replay logical changes (row inserts/updates/deletes) without requiring triggers on tables. The pg_receivellog tool would likely suit your purposes well when wrapped with a little scripting.

The downside is that you'd have to run a patched PostgreSQL 9.3, so I'm guessing if you can't change a table, running a bunch of experimental code that's likely to change incompatibly in future isn't going to be high on your priority list ;-) . It's included in the stock release of 9.4 though, see "changeset extraction".

### Testing the relfilenode timestamp won't work

You might think you could look at the modified timestamp(s) of the file(s) that back the table on disk. This won't be very useful:

- The table is split into extents, individual files that by default are 1GB each. So you'd have to find the most recent timestamp across them all.
- Autovacuum activity will cause these timestamps to change, possibly quite a while after corresponding writes happened.
- Autovacuum must periodically do an automatic 'freeze' of table contents to prevent transaction ID wrap-around. This involves progressively rewriting the table and will naturally change the timestamp. This happens even if nothing's been added for potentially quite a long time.
- Hint-bit setting results in small writes during `SELECT`. These writes will also affect the file timestamps.

### Examine the transaction logs

In theory you could attempt to decode the transaction logs with `pg_xlogreader` and find records that affect the table of interest. You'd have to try to exclude activity caused by vacuum, full page writes after hint bit setting, and of course the huge amount of activity from every other table in the entire database cluster.

The performance impact of this is likely to be huge, since every change to every database on the entire system must be examined.

All in all, adding a trigger on a table is trivial in comparison.

Comment: Very good information. Unfortunately, not adding triggers or altering table structure is an /administrative/ limitation, not /technical/. We actually are going with something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020033/how-can-i-get-a-hash-of-an-entire-table-in-postgresql as reviewing what we needed better, the goal was to have identical contents, not necessarily no changes (eg: `INSERT A; DELETE A` is an OK no-op). I tried to close my Q as a dupe, but your answer is by far the most thorough and useful!

Comment: If want to see whether there were any changes made with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` queries without altering tables, then logical replication is the perfect solution that now works with the latest PostgreSQL versions. This solution is a bit complex to set up and manage, here is an example of a project https://github.com/BemiHQ/bemi (I'm the author)

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a trigger on insert/update/delete events on the table?   The trigger could call a function that inserts a timestamp into another table which would mark the time for any table-changing event.

The only concern would be an update event updated using the same data currently in the table.  The trigger would fire, even though the table didn't really change. If you're concerned about this case, you could make the trigger call a function that generates a checksum against just the updated rows and compares against a previously generated checksum, which would usually be more efficient than scanning and checksumming the whole table.

Postgres documentation on triggers here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear originally, I see; we can't actually alter the table in any way. Good idea, though, and thanks for pointing out the “updated without changing” case — in another world, this would probably be what I'd have done for “Plan A.”

Answer (score 1):

If you simply just want to know when a table has last changed without doing anything to it, you can look at the actual file(s) timestamp(s) on your database server.

```
SELECT relfilenode FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'your_table_name';
```

If you need more detail on exactly where it's located, you can use:

```
select  t.relname,
        t.relfilenode,
        current_setting('data_directory')||'/'||pg_relation_filepath(t.oid)
from pg_class t
join pg_namespace ns on ns.oid = t.relnamespace
where relname = 'your_table_name';
```

Since you did mention that it's quite a big table, it will definitely be broken into segments, and toasts, but you can utilize the relfilenode as your base point, and do a ls -ltr relfilenode.* or relfilnode_*  where relfilenode is the actual relfilenode from above.

These files gets updated at every checkpoint if something occured on that table, so depending on how often your checkpoints occur, that's when you'll see the timestamps update, which if you haven't changed the default checkpoint interval, it's within a few minutes.

Another trivial, but imperfect way to check if INSERTS or DELETES have occurred is to check the table size:

```
SELECT pg_total_relation_size('your_table_name');
```

I'm not entirely sure why a trigger is out of the question though, since you don't have to make it retroactive.  If your goal is to ensure nothing changes in it, a trivial trigger that just catches an insert, update, or delete event could be routed to another table just to timestamp an attempt but not cause any activity on the actual table.  It seems like you're not ensuring anything changes though just by knowing that something changed.

Anyway, hope this helps you in this whacky problem you have...

Comment: Testing the relfilenode modification time won't work I'm afraid. It'll change when the database engine writes hint bits, which can happen during a regular `SELECT`, or when autovacuum goes through doing maintenance work.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice would be to add a `modified` column. If it were MySQL, I'd use timestamp as datatype for the field (updates to current date on each updade). Postgre must have something similar.

Comment: unfortunately, this is a “large” table in a production DB, so altering the table itself in any way isn't permitted. Good idea, though; and I'll clarify the Q.