# Finding out the hash value of a group of rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `person` in my PostgresSQL database, which contains data of different users.

I need to write a test case, which ensures that some routine does modify the data of user 1, and does not modify data of user 2.

For this purpose, I need to

a) calculate a hash code of all rows of user 1 and those of user 2,

b) then perform the operation under test,

c) calculate the hash code again and

d) compare hash codes from steps a) and c).

I found a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878499/finding-the-hash-value-of-a-row-in-postgresql) to calculate the hash code for a single row:

```
SELECT md5(CAST((f.*)AS text))
FROM person f;
```

In order to achieve my goal (find out whether rows of user 2 have been changed), I need to perform a query like this:

```
SELECT user_id, SOME_AGGREGATE_FUNCTION(md5(CAST((f.*)AS text)))
FROM person f
GROUP BY user_id;
```

What aggregate function can I use in order to calculate the hash code of a set of rows?

Note: I just want to know whether any rows of user 2 have been changed. I do not want to know, what exactly has changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way - just concat all the string form `md5` with `string_agg`. But to use this aggregate correctly you must specify `ORDER BY`.

Or use `md5(string_agg(md5(CAST((f.*)AS text)),''))` with some `ORDER BY` - it will change if any field of `f.*` changes and it is cheap to compare.

Comment: Thanks. When I try to use `string_agg` I get the error message `Function string_agg doesn't exist.`. I'm using Postgres 9.2.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Weird. Official manual says it exists. Here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Try now. I forgot the second parameter of `string_agg`, the delimiter.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko: You could simplify to `md5(f::text)` because you can cast the composite table type to `text` directly.

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler way to do it

```
SELECT user_id, md5(textin(record_out(A))) AS hash
FROM person A
```

Comment: Hi, how do you suggest to do if I want to make the hash only from a subset of columns of the table? `SELECT user_id, md5(textin(record_out(col1,col2,col3))) AS hash
FROM person` does not work, it gives and error like `ERROR: function record_out(text, text,integer) does not exist`

Comment: Seems I figured it: `SELECT user_id, md5(textin(record_out(row(col1,col2,col3)))) AS hash FROM person`